# Postgres on Kubernetes password authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I used this tutorial: https://severalnines.com/blog/using-kubernetes-deploy-postgresql

With my configuration on Kubernetes which is based off the official Docker Image I keep getting:

```
psql -h <publicworkernodeip> -U postgres -p <mynodeport> postgres
Password for user postgres: example
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

yamls:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
```

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:11
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres
      volumes:
        - name: postgres
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 5432
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 12Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 12Gi
```

Comment: If you started DB before with that volume but with different credentials - Postgres will refuse to overwrite existing data in volume. Can you try same thing with new volume ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried deleting everything and retrying, but the issue remains.

Comment: I think it is clearly pointing to role issue.

Comment: Yes, but is there additional step I need to create custom Dockerfile to enable connection?

Comment: can you try image bitnami/postgresql?

Comment: `bitnami/postgresql` works!  will happily use for now, but still wondering why my configuration has password issues. may have to do with `pg_hba.conf` (am just using official image postgres default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to login using the below command

psql -h $(hostname -i) -U postgres

```
kubectl exec -it postgres-566fbfb87c-rcbvd sh

# env
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=postgres


# psql -h $(hostname -i) -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql (11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c postgres
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
postgres=#
```

Comment: That allows connection, thank you! It seems setting the env variables are key rather than using --password and that `psql -U postgres` works without hostname as well. Do you have recommendations on how to expose this `Service` so I can connect from outside the Kubernetes cluster without kubectl exec? I am using `NodePort` and `postgresql://postgres:example@<publicworkernodeip>:<mynodeport>/postgres` does not seem to work.

Comment: you can try using nodeport type in your service definition

Comment: 34567 port is out of k8s range. use between 30000 - 32767

Comment: Oh sorry, I actually make a mistake. I was pointing to `bitnami/postgresql` Docker image, and that's why I was able to get past password authentication. Official `postgres` Docker image still asks for password and fails. Yes apologies, I am using `NodePort` (see original post) with port generated between 30000 - 32767.

Comment: This ended up working even with official Docker image once I corrected PV/PVC. Also yes, `NodePort` with `<workernodeip>:<nodeport>` is able to connect. Thank you.